# Примитивный бой с ботом в браузерке

Tags: php

Я сделал бой с ботом:

1) Мы бьем:

```
<?php

session_start();

$host = '';
$username = ''; 
$password = '';
$db_name = '';
$tbl_name = '';

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die("can't connect");
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $tbl_name");
mysql_query("UPDATE `enemy` SET `username`='".$_SESSION['username']."' ")or die(mysql_error()) ;
$sql = mysql_query("INSERT INTO `battle` (img,name,level,life,atk,def,type,username) SELECT img,name,level,life,atk,def,type,username FROM `enemy` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());
?>

<table>
  <tr>
  <TD><?php
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM startpoke WHERE id_poke = '".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die("can't connect") ;    
    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $result ) ){
      echo "<br>{$row['name_poke']}" ;
      echo " - {$row['level']} lvl";
      echo "<br>{$row['img']}"; 
    ?>
  <div style='width:250px;border:0px solid black;margin-center: 0%;'>
  <div align="left" style='center:0px;width:100%;background-color:green;'><?php       echo "{$row['all_life']}"; echo "/{$row['life']}";  ?></div>
<div style='width:250px;border:0px solid black;margin-center: 0%;'>
  <div align="left" style='center:0px;width:100%;background-color:blue;'><?php 
      echo "{$row['exp']}";  ?></div>
</TD>
<TD><a href="javascript: onClick=win1=window.open('def.php','width=650,height=400,scrollbars=yes');return true;"><?php echo "{$row['atk']}"; } ?></a></TD>

<TD><?php
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM battle WHERE username = '".$_SESSION['username']."'  LIMIT 1")or die(mysql_error());    while( $row = mysql_fetch_array( $res ) ){
echo "<br>{$row['name']}" ;
echo " - {$row['level']} lvl";
echo "<br> {$row['img']}";?>

<div style='width:250px;border:0px solid black'>
  <div align="left" style='center:0px;width:100%;background-color:green;'><?php  echo "{$row['life']}"; }  ?></div></TD>

</tr>
</table>
</center>
</body>
</html>
```

2) Нас бьют :

```
<?php
session_start();

$host = 
$username = 
$password =
$db_name =

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM battle WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$pok = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM startpoke WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

if($pok['life'] < 0 ){

mysql_query("DELETE FROM `pokelight620`.`battle` WHERE `battle`.`username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;

echo "Победа! <a href='loc=1.php'>Уйти</a>";
}
else{

if($row['life'] > 0 ){

 mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
 mysql_query("UPDATE `battle` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
 echo "<script>location.href='fight.php';</script>";

}
else{

 mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=0 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
 mysql_query("DELETE FROM `pokelight620`.`battle` WHERE `battle`.`username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;

echo "Вы проиграли! <a href='loc=1.php'>Уйти</a>";

}
}

?>
```

Извините за большой код, просто по другом никак! Так вот, когда страница fight.php (это когда нас бьют) обновляется, заносится еще один бот и постоянно приходится бить разных ботов,а нужно только одного, и вот я решил это все проверять логином пользователя, например: пользователь начал бой и на него напал бот, в таблице где весит сам бот есть столбик username куда заносится логин пользователя, а это значит что нужно вытянуть бота с логином пользователя, но так как страница fight.php постоянно обновляется, постоянно прибавляются боты с логином пользователя, а нужно вытягивать только одно, я решил сделать что если запись с логином пользователя уже есть значит не заносит нового бота, вопрос, как это сделать ? если можно то с кодом, заранее спасибо !

Comment: измените пожалуйста код. а то у меня не хочет

Comment: ставлю зуб, никто не ответит.

Comment: хех =)я тоже так думаю, но минусовать умеют все =)

Comment: >>ставлю зуб, никто не ответит.

@Ozim, на случай, если вы потрете коммент: надо было внимательнее следить. Я довольно часто приколу отвечаю. **ушел писать**

Comment: knes, спасибо вам большое =) Ozim, кто то пойдет к стоматологу =)

Comment: @knes, а, если не секрет, зачем? Чтобы идиотские вопросы, ответы на которые есть в любой книжке объемом с методичку, плодились дальше?)

Comment: Не секрет. 9x% всех вопросов тут есть в той или иной методичке, разжеванные и разобранные до мелочей. Оставшиеся 10-x процентов делится на 9y% разобранных на форумах, типа стэковерфлоу и 10-y%, которые действительно требуют внимания.  
Но задача этого сообщества собрать все ответы в одну кучу. Чтобы надо было просмотреть ОДИН источник и получить ответ. Причем вне зависимости от уровня подготовки и способности говорить с гуглом на одном языке.  
Осталось чуток: дождаться, когда же тут заработает нормальный поиск, а не то подобие, которое тут не работает. %)

Comment: Prikol, хочу выразить вам свою признательность! Чем больше таких как вы, тем ценнее я как специалист!

ЗЫ: Это не слова обиды, а мотивации. Задумайтесь, прочитайте несколько книжек, попробуйте сделать что-то разобравшись во всём сам. Вот тогда к вам придет эйфория и гордость за сделанное.

Comment: @knes, то есть бесполезность вопросов (в значит, и ответов) вас не смущает?) Не, одно дело нубские вопросы, которые показывают, что человеку нужно что-то кроме результата, а тут же явно видно, что автору проще выпрашивать и ныть, чем тупо почитать кинжку >_< 

В общем как хотите, карма не пахнет)) я буду продолжать минусовать, до бана)

Comment: @knes это пройдет, в следующий раз он вывалит всю свою (вашу) тонну кода, которую вам надо будет перепроверить, а потом начнет писать другую игру, и будет знать, что можно даже не пытаться самому начать учить элементарные вещи, с уверенностью могу сказать - вы ему не помогаете, вы его губите, как программиста.

Comment: Sh4dow, так вот какой критик меня заминусовал, я с вами согласен книга это круто, но норм книга в Киева стоит от 300грн. И мне как то в облом тратить такие деньги! И к тому же я ответы не копирую, они переделаны мной! Хотите могу показать весь исходник!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Например, есть вариант такой:

```
<?php
session_start();

mysql_connect($host, $username, $password) or die(mysql_error()) ;
mysql_select_db($db_name) or die(mysql_error());
$res = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM battle WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'");
$pok = mysql_fetch_array($res);

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM startpoke WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'");
$row = mysql_fetch_array($sql);

while($pok['life'] > 0){
    if($row['life'] > 0 ){
        mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_query("UPDATE `battle` SET `life`=`life`-3 WHERE username='".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
        echo "<script>location.href='fight.php';</script>";
    }else{
        mysql_query("UPDATE `startpoke` SET `life`=0 WHERE id_poke='".$_SESSION['id']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
        mysql_query("DELETE FROM `pokelight620`.`battle` WHERE `battle`.`username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
        echo "Вы проиграли! <a href='loc=1.php'>Уйти</a>";
        exit();
    }
    flush();//Это чтобы показывался каждый ход, даже если их будет очень много.
}
mysql_query("DELETE FROM `pokelight620`.`battle` WHERE `battle`.`username` = '".$_SESSION['username']."'")or die(mysql_error()) ;
echo "Победа! <a href='loc=1.php'>Уйти</a>";

?>
```

1. Нам не надо перегружать страницу каждый раз. (Вспомните бой, который я тебе когда-то писал).
   Это сократит нагрузку на сервер в разы. Остальные ошибки не правил: мне лень создавать базу и проверять. Но направление деятельности такое. Это как можно сделать.
2. Если делать с перезагрузкой, то можно завести две сессионные переменные
   $_SESSION['pok'] и $_SESSION['row'], в которые занести вытянутые из базы значения для ID  дерущихся покемонов. Тогда при каждой загрузке мы будем вытягивать из бд одних и тех же монстриков. Так делать НЕ рекомендуется.
3. А как же рекомендуется?
   Вытягиваем из БД ОДИН раз покемона и врага. По циклу пробегаем бой до смерти одного из них(не надо обновлять БД на каждый удар!). Выплевываем результат боя. Заносим в БД изменения.
4. Как сделать, чтобы бой был длинным?(типа, задержка между ударами)
   Делаем как в пункте 3. Но при помощи javascript показываем не сразу все, а частями, используя функцию set_interval или set_timeout.

P.S. народ, вообще-то, вопрос интересный, зря вы так. Другое дело, Прикол опять настолько увлекся разработкой, что безумно захотел минусов. В итоге, вопрос задал криво. ^^

P.S. [[@Ozim](/users/2690/ozim)](/users/2690/ozim):
  `|O      O| 
@|   ..   |@
 |UUUUUUUU| 
 |ПППП ППП|`

Comment: спасибо большое , вы как всегда самые классные =)

Comment: хех =) у меня бой идет минут 5 и сбивает где то 5к хп=(